# Symfony 2 JMS Serializer Bundle - Serialize only IDs for User friends

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I have a question about the JMS Serializer Bundle in Symfony 2.

I want to serialize a User entity, which has a many-to-many relation with itself called "friends".

While I want to expose a bunch of property from the original User, I only want the ids from the friend objects, which are also User entities.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, while I wrote the question, I also solved it.

The solution is to use the @VirtualProperty annotation.

Example:

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\VirtualProperty;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;

// ...

/**
 * @VirtualProperty
 * @SerializedName("friends")
 */
public function getFriendIdsOnly()
{
    $friendIds = array();
    foreach ($this->friends as $friendEntity) {
        $friendIds[] = $friendEntity->getId();
    }
    return $friendIds;
}
```

With this, the "friends" key will contain an array of User ids.

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe you could use the @Groups annotation.

```
class User
{
    /*
     * @JMS\Groups({"user_id", "friend_id"})
     */
    $id;

    /*
     * @JMS\Groups({"user_friends"})
     */
    $friends;
}
```

And when you want to serialize you set up the `["user_friends", "friend_id"]` groups. The difference with your solution is the format of the return (if we talk about json)

```
// You
{"id":, "friends":["id", "id"]}

// Me
{"id":, "friends":[{"id":}, {"id":}]}
```

The solution with the groups allow a more manageable return. If one day you want to send back the username for instance, you just need to change the groups annotations.

Comment: An intersting solution, thanks for that! Although I posted the question with my answer - and so I had to accept that - I upvote your post, and thank you for your insight.

Comment: It was just to give an alternative :)